# I can't find Ubuntu in my list of operating systems

Tags: partitioning

I had to download ubuntu for a class. I used a flash drive with 64gb and Rufus to put ubuntu on the drive. I installed by booting from the drive and following all the steps. It partitioned it into some drive. It was the only one I had available. However, once I restarted the computer, it immediately booted windows 10 (I did do a dual boot thing). I tried switching the default from the control panel but couldn't even find ubuntu. All that's there is windows 10.

I tried to reinstall it, thinking I messed up the first time. However, the installer says that ubuntu and windows are both already on the computer. This is making me want to pull my hair out.

Comment: did you install EFI  mode? check the ESP (EFI system partition) for the file /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi or /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

Comment: How do I get there?

Comment: boot from a LiveCD. use gparted to turn off the ESP flag. inspect the contents. then un mount the drive and turn the flag back on.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I was booting in Legacy for some reason and not uefi